How to install apps directly from Android Studio or self-built APKs in Android 15 Private Space?
Android 15 Preview introduced Private Space, a secure, isolated environment for installing apps.
I am trying to install an app on the emulator, but it redirects me to the Play Store, and it seems like I can only install apps from there. Is it possible to install apps directly from Android Studio or by using self-built APKs in Private Space? If so, how can I achieve this?

Unlock Private Space, long press on the App icon, Install in private. However, the option leads me to Play Store.

Hope this helps it is using adb and the user flag, didn't try it yet
https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/post/android-private-space-apps/
posting the link because is not my work, and people deserve credit.

You can create a new build configuration like this

make sure to check the two options marked in the red box.
